# Instant APP InflateException

Tags: android, android-appcompat, inflate-exception, android-instant-apps

When running my Instant App, I get the following inflateException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xfzj.instantappdemo/com.xfzj.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                             at com.xfzj.instantappdemo.feature.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
</pre>
```

Here is my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.xfzj.instantappdemo2.feature.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my feature module build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
}
```

If I run the installed app it succeeds.

Is `com.android.support:design:25.4.0` not compatible with instant app?

Answer (score 1):

`com.android.support:design:25.4.0` is supported by Instant Apps. The issue is duplicate dependencies on the *appcompat* and *design support* libraries between the feature modules. Typically since these libraries are common across features, they will be included in the base feature module's `build.gradle` file (example from Android Studio building a default Instant App project):

```
dependencies {
    application project(':app')
    feature project(':feature')
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    api 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
}
```

Since other feature modules have a dependency on the base feature module, they should not include these libraries themselves. The feature module's `build.gradle` just needs to include:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':base')
    ...
 }
```

In other words, all libraries defined in the base feature module are available to the other features and they should not be re-added as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Since both instant and installed app share design library, dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0
```

should be in base feature `build.gradle` file, not in `installed`.

If you want to include it to some non-base feature, make sure both instant and installed `build.gradle` files include this feature.

Comment: It's in feature build.gradle,not in installed.

Comment: Does both instant and installed has the feature dependency in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes，they both  has the feature dependency.I decompile instant app's codes, find  android.support.v7 and design and so on  in it.

Comment: Did it fix the problem?